Activating an Application in Odoo 18 Gives Model Not Found Error
I have a Model not found: meeting.management for this particular code snippet below and I do not understand why. I am using Odoo 18. So the error comes up after the application/module has already been installed and when trying to activate it. The structure of my application is as follows
meeting_management
|_controllers
|_models , this contains the model class MeetingManagement.py
|_views  , the xml files that contain meeting_creation.xml which tries to access the    meeting.management model but fails
|_static , contains some Javascript and other artifacts
# models/meeting.py

from odoo import models, fields

class MeetingManagement(models.Model):
    _name = 'meeting.management'
    _description = 'Meeting Management'

    space_id = fields.Char(string='Matterport Link', required=True)
    devices = fields.Many2many('meeting.device', string='Devices')
    microphone = fields.Boolean(string='Microphone')
    speaker = fields.Boolean(string='Speaker')
    audio = fields.Selection([('stereo', 'Stereo'), ('mono', 'Mono')], string='Audio')
    participant_name = fields.Char(string='Participant Name')

    def create_meeting(self):
        # Implement logic to create meeting
        # Generate meeting ID and return it
        return 'Generated Meeting ID'

    def join_meeting(self):
        # Implement logic to join meeting
        # Redirect or process further actions
        pass


<!-- views/meeting_creation.xml -->
<odoo>
    <record id="meeting_creation_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">meeting.creation.form</field>
        <field name="model">meeting.management</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Create Meeting">
                <group>
                    <field name="space_id" placeholder="Enter Matterport Link"/>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="create_meeting" string="Create Meeting" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>


Error that I get is

RPC_ERROR

Odoo Server Error

Occured on localhost:8069 on model ir.module.module and id 9 on 2024-10-09 08:55:28 GMT

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1954, in _transactioning
    return service_model.retrying(func, env=self.env)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 137, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1921, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 2168, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 330, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 728, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 40, in call_button
    action = call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 517, in call_kw
    result = getattr(recs, name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-79>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 75, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 477, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(self.env.registry[self._name].button_install)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 601, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in new
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\tools\func.py", line 97, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 131, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 479, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(env, graph,
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 363, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 226, in load_module_graph
    load_data(env, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 70, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(env, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 608, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(env, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 679, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 594, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "C:\coding\odoo development\17\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 548, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError(msg) from None  # Restart with "--log-handler odoo.tools.convert:DEBUG" for complete traceback
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/coding/odoo%20development/17/custom_modules/meeting_management/views/meeting_creation.xml:3
Error while validating view near:

<form string="Create Meeting" __validate__="1">
                <group>
                    <field name="space_id" placeholder="Enter Matterport Link"/>

Model not found: meeting.management

View error context:
{'file': 'c:\\coding\\odoo '
         'development\\17\\custom_modules\\meeting_management\\views\\meeting_creation.xml',
 'line': 1,
 'name': 'meeting.creation.form',
 'view': ir.ui.view(266,),
 'view.model': 'meeting.management',
 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(),
 'xmlid': 'meeting_creation_form'}


The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    RPCError@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/b23fe77/web.assets_web.min.js:3053:338
    makeErrorFromResponse@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/b23fe77/web.assets_web.min.js:3056:163
    rpc._rpc/promise</<@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/b23fe77/web.assets_web.min.js:3061:34
    

I tried checking to see if the model is available on the Odoo server and I can not see it.

Very simple question: do you import models/meeting.py in your __init__.py

Yes, I import that init.py within the models folder as "from . import meeting".
I may have figured out the issue to some extent, I had not imported the models folder in the main applications directory init.py as "from . import models".

That's actually the import i meant, but nice that you've solved your issue ;-)
